# Accessing $_POST data in drupal

Tags: php, html, forms, post, drupal-6

I am creating a form in a drupal Page which submits data to another drupal page ( `'../configurator/process_order')`.

```
var orderObject = { //JS Object with Data to Post
            priceUnit:priceUnit, 
            priceTotal: priceTotal, 
            priceCount: count 
        }; 
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.style.display = 'none';
        form.action = "../configurator/process_order"; //Target URL
        form.method = "post"; 
        form.target = "_blank";

        for (var key in orderObject) // create Input Elements from JS Object
        {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.name = key;
            input.value = orderObject[key];
            form.appendChild(input);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(form); 
        form.submit();
```

The page specified in `action` parameter opens but if i try to access any of the submitted data nothing happens.

```
<div>
    <?php echo $_POST["priceUnit"]; ?>
</div>
```

If i do the same outside of drupal it is working. How can I access `$_POST` data in drupal and what is the easiest way to do so? (I am Using Drupal 6)

As alternative answer: is there another way to post data between drupal pages in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have to change this in your code:

```
input.value = orderObject[key];
```

to

```
input.value = orderObject[value];
```

And you can try to check if it posts any values at all?

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```